# Excluding files from logrotate when one filename contains brackets

Tags: bash, logrotate

I need to exclude filenames containing a certain string from logrotate.
Currently I have tried this common solution in the logrotate.conf file:

```
/something/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 30
  compress
  prerotate
     bash -c "[[ ! \"$1\" =~ unwanted ]]"
  endscript
}
```

Unfortunately the directory includes a filename similar to:

```
/something/(xxx).log
```

Which results in an error when the prerotate script is run:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected token `(', conditional binary operator expected
```

I've tried $1 without quotes, with single quotes with the same error. How can I exclude filenames containing the string "unwanted" when there are log files in the directory whose names contain brackets?

Comment: Could you try this `bash -c "[[ ! \"$1\" = ~unwanted ]]"` with a space added beween `=` and `~` ?

Comment: No difference. It's the bracket inside the substitution for $1 that causes the issue.